# Is it possible to eliminate "empty" facets with Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've finally managed to get Elastic Search indexing to work the way I want it to work, indexing the raw values of certain fields using subfields and `not_analyzed`. The facets are what I expect, however, in some cases, due to the source data having null/empty values for those fields, I get results like this in the facets section:

```
  "things": {
     "_type": "terms",
     "missing": 187,
     "total": 12214,
     "other": 10608,
     "terms": [
        {
           "term": "foo",
           "count": 912
        },
        {
           "term": "",
           "count": 532
        },
        {
           "term": "bar",
           "count": 37
        }
     }
  }
```

Note the "" in the second item. I can see why ElasticSearch wouldn't automatically exclude this, as one might want to know how many documents don't have the field. But for my purposes I'd like to just not have this returned.

Is there some way that I can configure ElasticSearch to ignore these, either in the indexing or in the query?

Comment: Have you tried [excluding](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_excluding_terms) an empty string? Not sure if that would work, though, but give it a try.

Comment: It might be easier to simply remove the field from your document in the first place, though. Within the app in which you collect the data to send it to ES.

Comment: @Thorsten: I *could* remove the field, but this is a fairly deeply nested field in a document that's being automatically serialized by NEST, so it would involve almost a total rewrite of that code, unless it has some setting to ignore null/empty strings (which I couldn't find). Excluding is most likely the (simple) answer, I'm pretty new to ES and forgot about that option.

Answer (score 9):

Try putting

```
        "exclude" : ""
```

in your aggregation terms